# How to get bash history of already running session?

Tags: bash

How to get bash history of already running session?

1.) I was thrown out of my server because of a cable fault. 
2.) I logged in again using a new session. History of the other session is not accessible.
2.) I want the bash history from the other session.

Any ideas if this can be accomplished? (I know of methods how to change this for the future)

Answer (score 2):

If you send `SIGHUP` or `SIGTERM` to your previous bash session, it should terminate and write out its history. Once that's done, start a new bash session (or just look in your `~/.bash_history` file) to access the command history.

So in summary, use something like `ps -fu <your_username> | grep bash` to find the PID of your previous bash session, then `kill <bash_pid>`.